# generate a preview of markdown on flask form

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to make an interface very much like this text box and preview below it on stack overflow question form. I use `hoep` to handle the markup on my flask backend. The following is my code for the page.

#### Flask

```
@bp.route('/write', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def write():
    form = WritePostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        extensions = hoep.EXT_FENCED_CODE
        html = hoep.render(form.text.data, extensions)
        p = Post(
            title=form.title.data,
            body=html,
            author=current_user._get_current_object()
        )
        db.session.add(p)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('posts.post', post_id=p.id))
    return render_template("post/write.html", form=form)
```

However, while I am working in my writing form, I wish to generate some sort of preview *as hoep would render it*.

The immediate solution I thought of was making a request to the server on some kind of `$('input').change` event, and returning the rendered result of hoep compilation.

The problem is that this would simply be too many requests and it would be too slow, as the posts can get fairly long and hoep looking through it every time. a `_.debounce` might help a bit but still seems a less than elegant solution

How would this be implemented in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons you should have a client-side markdown renderer that generates the live preview. Once the form is submitted you can then apply your server-side renderer to generate the final HTML.

StackOverflow uses a library called [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) for the client-side renderer. I have written the [Flask-PageDown](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-pagedown-markdown-editor-extension-for-flask-wtf) extension that integrates with Flask-WTF and gives you a new field type that comes with a preview.

Comment: oh I saw that library briefly, but didn't know it had a preview feature! Thank you sir